# Merge Vertical Cells in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Is there anyway I can merge vertical cells in Google Docs? Without resorting to editing the HTML code, of course.

Comment: I hate stack overflow mods. How is this off topic? I came here looking for this answer, but apparently super users don't need to know how to stretch the capabilities of their software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still isn't supported by Google Docs. Suggest it [here](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=featuresuggest).